# Passing Dynamic value inside Object which has array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code I need to pass a dynamic value
(for eg - Message: 'DP' Missing stamp in the header)

In Error object with the Message field, i need to add dynamic value. What is the correct way to pass dynamic values?

```
var Error =
    {
        value:
        [
            { Code: 'Error1', Message: "Missing stamp in header" }

        ]
    }
```

```
function ErrorCode(erCode) {
    var err = serviceErrors.errors.filter(function (er) {
        return er.Code == erCode
    });

   
}
```

```
function validateRequestHeaders(req) {
    var Error = { value: [] };
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if(req.header("stamp").toLowerCase() !== 'dp'){
                Error.value.push(ErrorCode("Error1"));
            }
        }

        resolve(Error);

    })
}
```